# Setting up Content Synchronization module

Tags: 8

## Blanca.Esqueda,

I'm interested in using your Content Synchronization but am having a little bit of problem getting it to run. I'm using Drupal 8 on Acquia Devdesktop, running Content Synchronization 8.x-2.0 using PHP version 7.1.12. The installation instructions is a bit cryptic to me (see image below).

[image: d8_settings.php image]
Where do you put this in settings.php? I just appended it to the last lines. But then where is ../content/sync pointing to (see image below)?

[image: d8_settings.php]

After all that I'm getting:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=17&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: 500 Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I would love to use the Content Synchronization module. Can you give me a hand on this?

Thank you very much for your help,
Kai

Answer (score 5):

`$app_root` is the top directory of your website. The one where your `index.php` is located.

Therfore the `../content/sync` is a location like this:

```
- content
    - sync
- public_html
    - index.php
    - (all the Drupal 8 files)
```

To add to that — this is probably done out of security reasons. Not to store your data from DB with the code. Same reasoning was followed for the Config Management core module.

And lastly - you have to make sure there is such a location on your server. Locate index.php, go one directory up and locate or create the `content/sync` path and try again.

Comment: A suggestion would be to use `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant for replacing `$app_root`